# Apache Spark Streaming : simple receivers

Tags: rest, rss, rpc, spark-streaming

Is there a simple means to connect spark streaming to external sources like Rest server, RSS stream, RPC server, ...?

Answer (score 0):

You can create custom receiver and write a logic to connect to external data source. Custom receivers will be entry point for your incoming data.